# Ajax.Updater POST params not transmitted by Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, prototypejs, parameters

I am debugging code written by someone else - I am also a newbie at Ajax and JS. The code shown below uses Ajax (Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.6.0.1) to submit a simple contact form and update the page with the response. It works perfectly with IE8 and fails with Firefox.  I have traced the failure to the post parameters. The target file, mail.php, is not receiving any POST parameters when Firefox is the browser. Not just the values are missing - the params are not defined in the post. The URL is valid. The form, the Ajax JS files and the mail.php script are all on the same domain.

I have tried variations on defining var params as shown in several other Stack Overflow posts (inline, different assignment methods, etc). All produced the same results as the code below.

Any clue what is wrong?

```
FF results
Please try again. responseText='', url='http://domain.com/builder/mail.php', 
form_name='dom', form_message='testing', form_email='dom@domain.com', 
form_to='info@domain.com'

IE8 results
Message Sent!

JS function
function sendForm(F)
{
    $("contact_form").hide();
    $("ajax-loader").show();

    var url = site_url+'mail.php';

    var form_message = escape($("message").value);
    var form_name = escape($("name").value);
    var form_address = escape($("address").value);
    var form_phone = escape($("phone").value);
    var form_email = escape($("email").value);
    var form_how_learn = escape($("how_learn").value);
    var form_to = escape($("to").value);

    var params = {message: form_message, 
                name: form_name, 
                address: form_address, 
                phone: form_phone, 
                email: form_email, 
                how_learn: form_how_learn,
                to: form_to};

    var ajax = new Ajax.Updater(
        'contact_form',
        url, 
        {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: params,
            onComplete: function (response) 
            {
                $("ajax-loader").hide();
                if (response.responseText == "ok")
                {
                    $("contact_form").innerHTML = "<p style=\"color:green;\">Message Sent!</p>";
                    $("contact_form").show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Debug code added
                    $("contact_form").innerHTML = "<p style=\"color:red;\">Please try again."+
                        " responseText='"+response.responseText+"',"+
                        " url='"+url+"',"+
                        " form_name='"+form_name+"',"+
                        " form_message='"+form_message+"',"+
                        " form_email='"+form_email+"',"+
                        " form_to='"+form_to+"'"+
                        "</p>";
                    $("contact_form").show();
                }
            },
            onFailure: function ()
            {
                $("ajax-loader").hide();
                $("contact_form").innerHTML = "<p style=\"color:red;\">Please try again.</p>";
                $("contact_form").show();
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine in my Firefox and sends a valid POST request with all parameters set. I only changed one thing: you should not escape the parameter values on your own, Prototype will handle that for you.

Comment: @JulianD, Intriguing - I always like simpler code. I tried removing escape() from around the parameter values. Didn't fix my issue, but it does give me ideas for further exploration. Thanks.